# Transforming Multiple ggplot into Economist Theme

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am hoping to take this code and:

1. Convert to theme_economist()
2. Have a common legend located on top for all plots

I recognise that this script is probably not the best, but hopefully there's a quick and easy way to convert the multiple plots into the economist theme with one common legend.  Code is below.

```
discharge_data <- read.csv("discharge_stats_2.csv")
charge_data <- read.csv("chargestats.csv")
# PLOT 1 Voltage versus Battery Capacity Discharge (Ah)
    p1 <- ggplot(data=discharge_data) +
    # -15
    geom_line(aes(x=ahminus15,y=voltageminus15,colour="-15°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
      # -5
      geom_line(aes(x=ahminus5,y=voltageminus5,colour="-5°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    # 0 
    geom_line(aes(x=ah0,y=voltage0,colour="0°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    # +5
    geom_line(aes(x=ah5,y=voltage5,colour="+5°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    ggtitle("Voltage versus Capacity (Ah) During Discharge\n") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5,
                                  vjust=2.12, 
                                  colour="black",
                                  size = 8))+
    xlab("Battery Capacity (Ah)") + ylab("Voltage (V)") + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=0.5,face="bold",size=12))+theme(axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=0.5,face="bold",size=12))+
    scale_x_reverse()+
    guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Test Temperatures"))

# PLOT 2 BATTERY VOLTAGE VERSUS TIME TO DISCHARGE
    p2 <- ggplot(data=discharge_data) +
    # -15
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(timeminus15,format="%H:%M:%OS"),y=whminus15,colour="-15°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    # -5
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(timeminus5,format="%H:%M:%OS"),y=whminus5,colour="-5°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    # 0 
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(time0,format="%H:%M:%OS"),y=wh0,colour="0°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    # +5
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(time5,format="%H:%M:%OS"),y=wh5,colour="+5°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    ggtitle("Discharge Time versus Voltage\n") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.15, 
                                vjust=2.12, 
                                colour="black",
                                size = 8,
                                face="bold"))+
    xlab("Time to Discharge") + ylab("Battery Capacity (Wh)") + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=0.5,face="bold",size=12))+theme(axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=0.5,face="bold",size=12))+
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(l = 15, r=15,b=15)))+
    theme(legend.position="none")

    

# PLOT 3 
    p3 <- ggplot(data=charge_data) +
    # -15
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(timeminus15,format="%H:%M"),y=currentminus15,colour="-15°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    # -5
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(timeminus5,format="%H:%M"),y=currentminus5,colour="-5°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    # 0 
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(time0,format="%H:%M"),y=current0,colour="0°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    # +5
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(time5,format="%H:%M"),y=current5,colour="+5°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M")+
    ggtitle("Charge Time Versus Current\n") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.15, 
                                vjust=2.12, 
                                colour="black",
                                size =8,
                                face="bold"))+
    xlab("Time to Max Charge (hrs)") + ylab("Battery Current (A)") + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=0.5,face="bold",size=12))+theme(axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=0.5,face="bold",size=12))+
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(l = 15, r=15,b=15)))+   theme(legend.position="none")

# PLOT 4
    p4 <- ggplot(data=charge_data) +
    # -15
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(timeminus15,format="%H:%M"),y=whminus15,colour="-15°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    # -5
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(timeminus5,format="%H:%M"),y=whminus5,colour="-5°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    # 0 
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(time0,format="%H:%M"),y=wh0,colour="0°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    # +5
    geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(time5,format="%H:%M"),y=wh5,colour="+5°C"),linewidth=1.5)+
    ggtitle("Charge Time Versus Battery Capacity (Wh)\n") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.15, 
                                vjust=2.12, 
                                colour="black",
                                size = 8,
                                face="bold"))+
    xlab("Time to Max Charge (hrs)") + ylab("Battery Capacity (Wh)") + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=0.5,face="bold",size=12))+theme(axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=0.5,face="bold",size=12))+
    scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M")+
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(l = 15, r=15,b=15)))+   theme(legend.position="none")
    
    p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + plot_layout(guides="collect") &  scale_colour_manual(labels =c("-15°C","-5°C","0°C","+5°C"), breaks =c("-15°C","-5°C","0°C","+5°C"), values=c("lightblue","blue","orange","red"))
```

Edit*   Here's the updated figure adding `& theme_economist()`
[image]

Comment: Try `& theme_economist()` to apply the theme to all plots in your patchwork.

Comment: Thanks Stefan.  I added a screenshot to show you what the output looks like. 
I'm hoping to remove the second legend on the right hand side, "colours", but keep the "Test Temperatures" legend.  Any ideas! Thanks for the help!

Comment: The issue is that you set the legend title only for the first plot via `guides`. Doing so the legends will not get merged, i.e. you have to set the same title for all plots. Or set it at the end for the patchwork using `& labs(color = "Test Temperatures")`